# Get my search to solve only if solution is negative (MIT6.00)

Tags: python, python-2.7

Folks,

I am getting my head stuck in knots here with problem 3 from PS1 in MIT6.00. I have written a couple of functions (one bisection search, and one function modelling the credit card debt). The problem is that it converges on a solution that gives a slightly positive remaining credit card balance. I could lower the tolerance in the bisection search, but I wanted to know if there was some more elegant way of making this optimiser return only negative results.

Cheers,

Aiden

code:

```
import numpy as np

def bisection(a, b, fun, tol, var = None):
    """Note that this only works if you put the independant variable
    as the first argument in the parameter """
    #def tstr(x):
    #    return 2*(x**2) - 3*x + 1
    #sol = bisection(0,0.9,tstr,0.1)

    c = (a+b)/2.0  

    if var != None:
        arga = var[:]
        argc = var[:]
        arga.insert(0,a)
        argc.insert(0,c)
    else:
        arga = a
        argc = c

    if (b-a)/2.0 <= tol:
        #Debugging print statement 1:
        #print 'SOL1: c = ', c
        if var != None:
            return [c] + fun(argc)
        else:
            return c

    if fun(argc)[0] == 0:
        if var != None:
            return [c] + fun(argc)
        else:
            return c
    elif fun(arga)[0]*fun(argc)[0] < 0:
        b = c
    else:
        a = c
    return bisection(a, b, fun, tol, var)


"""
Now we have defined a version of the paidOff function to work
with the bisection method"""

def paidOffBis(args):#(Pay, Bal, Apr):
    """Tester for Bisection Implementation"""
    # TEST SIZE OF args:
    if (type(args) != list)|(np.size(args) != 3):
        print 'Incorrect size or type of input, input size:', np.size(args), '-', args
        return None
    Pay, Bal, Apr = args
    Mpr = Apr/12.0
    Baln = Bal
    Nm = 0
    for n in range(12):
        Baln = Baln*(1 + Mpr) - Pay
        if (Baln < 0)&(Nm == 0):
            Nm = n + 1   
    if Baln < 0:
        return [Baln, Nm]
    else:
        return [Baln, Nm]

Out_Bal = float(raw_input('Enter the outstanding balance on your credit card: '))
Apr = float(raw_input('Enter the annual credit card interest rate as a decimal: '))

varin = [Out_Bal, Apr]

#(Out_Bal*(1 + (Apr/12.0))**12.0)/12.0
sol = bisection(Out_Bal/12.0, Out_Bal, paidOffBis, 0.01, varin)

print 'RESULT'
print 'Monthly payment to pay off debt in 1 year: $%.2f' % sol[0]
print 'Number of months needed:', sol[2]
print 'Balance: $%.2f' % sol[1]
```

Comment: Are you taking the edX class?

Comment: Yes, well, I am doing the OpenCourseWare version. I am not sure what the difference is.

Comment: Can't recall exactly but the edX conduct rules prohibit or limit seeking problem set answers outside of their forums.  If you are doing the OCW course on your own the everything is hunky-dory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure a balance less than or equal to zero you need to set your conditional statements correctly - you need to keep searching till that criteria is met.  You asked for `... a more elegant way ...`.  Using descriptive names for your variables and keeping it simple would certainly improve your code.  Here is one way to craft a solution using a bisection search.

```
annualInterestRate = .1
balance = 1000

def balance_after_one_year(balance, annualInterestRate, payment):
    '''Calculate the balance after one year of interest and payments.

    balance --> int or float
    annualInterestRate --> float between 0 and 1
    payment --> float

    returns float
    '''
    for _ in xrange(12):
        balance = (balance - payment) * (1 + annualInterestRate / 12.0)
    return balance

def min_payment(balance, annualInterestRate, tolerance = .01):
    '''Find the minimum payment to pay off a loan.

    Uses a bisection search.
    Ensures balance is not positive.

    balance --> float, int
    annualInterestRate --> float less than one
    tolerance --> float
   '''

    # we want the tolerance to be negative
    # this isn't strictly a tolerance, it is a lower limit
    tolerance = -abs(tolerance)

    hi = balance
    lo = 0
    while True:
        payment = (hi + lo) / 2.0
        tmp_balance = balance_after_one_year(balance, annualInterestRate, payment)
        if tmp_balance < tolerance:
            hi = payment
        # ensure balance is not positive
        elif tmp_balance > 0:
            lo = payment
        else:
            return payment, tmp_balance
```

Usage:

```
min_pmt, final_balance = min_payment(balance, annualInterestRate)
print 'minimum payment', min_pmt
print 'final balance', final_balance
```

Comment: Oh brilliant. You're right, that's much easier to understand. Thanks a lot.